# Shooting at cover with a rocket launcher

Tags: frozen-synapse

While looking at some replays, I have seen soldiers manage to hit cover - blocks and windows - using a rocket launcher. However, when I shoot at cover with a rocket it sails over the top and hits whatever is behind it.

Obviously, sometimes you want one result, sometimes the other, so how do I order a rocket solider to explicitly shoot *at* cover or *over* cover?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your unit is ducking when it fires, the rocket will hit cover, while if your unit is standing while firing, it will fire over the cover.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'd best not let my rocketeers duck behind windows for cover when trying to shoot then.